# HTML Form to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables

I have a script. This script has to do some calculations. For the reason that now the user has to edit the script variables in the file I want to write a form that updates the variables always when the form is updated. There are around 10 variables that needs to be updated always when one variable in the form is updated.

For example:

In the HTML form are 10 fields like this one (the `onchange="formChanged()"` is from the try):

```
<input type="number" name="pL" step="0.001" value="250000" onchange="formChanged()"/><br>
```

So I want to edit this variable in JavaScript:

```
var pL=250000;
```

I tried this:

```
function formChanged() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("x")[0].value
    var m0 = document.getElementsByName("pL")[0].value
    var V = document.getElementsByName("V")[0].value
}
```

But this doesn't work...
Do you have any suggestions, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you should really get a book and start learning js, this is far too trivial, `m0.value`

Comment: Can you share your complete onchange function?

Comment: sorry durring copying I've forgotten the `.value` @slash197 is it now better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

It should be `getElementsByName`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="number" name="pL" step="0.001" value="250000" onchange="formChanged()"/><br>
<input type="number" name="x" step="0.001" value="250000" onchange="formChanged()"/><br>
<input type="number" name="V" step="0.001" value="250000" onchange="formChanged()"/><br>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>function formChanged() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("x")[0].value
    var m0 = document.getElementsByName("pL")[0].value
    var V = document.getElementsByName("V")[0].value
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + ' ' + m0 + ' ' + V;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This works. Add a snippet with the whole code, please.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it seems that this wasn't the only error... :(

Comment: See my edit. @Ibrahim answer is not true for `input`, see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the value of the variable through javascript, assign the value to it's value property.

so instead of

```
pL=250000;
```

write, in your formChanged function

```
document.getElementsByName("pL")[0].value=250000;
```

also it is not clear from your question on the calculation you want to do on the
if say you want to add the values x and V to be the new pL
then write

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("x")[0].value
var m0 = document.getElementsByName("pL")[0].value
var V = document.getElementsByName("V")[0].value
document.getElementsByName("pL")[0].value=Number(x)+Number(V)
```

Answer (score -2):

In HTML5, the "name" attribute is deprecated and has been replaced by the "id" attribute for many elements. I've tried the following and it worked for me.

```
<input type="number" id="pL" step="0.001" value="250000" onchange="formChanged()"/>

<script>
function formChanged() {
    var m0 = document.getElementById("pL").value;
    alert("The current value is " + m0);
}
</script>
```

Let me know if this works for you too. Also make sure you put semi-colons after your statements in the formChanged() function.

Comment: The `name` attribute for form elements is _not_ 'deprecated' or obsolete: see [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#naming-form-controls-the-name-attribute).